# Using new Js and Css scripts in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a wordpress plugin. I want the plugin to work on as many wordpress installations as possible.

In order to use various js and css scripts in the plugin. I want to make use of 
wp_register_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );

My doubt is that, for eg. I have to use plupload functionality. On referring the documentation.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Link_Scripts_Only_on_a_Plugin_Administration_Screen. I found that plupload script is included under default script.

How do I determine, that the wordpress installation has the script as default. This could be for any wordpress version. so that I do not have to manually add the scripts as a part of my plugin.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Browsing WordPress versions, I see that `/wp-includes/js/plupload/` was introduced on [**version 3.3**](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3#wp-includes/js). You can creat a check for versions lower than 3.3 in your `register_activation_hook` (and display an `admin_notice` or abort the installation). Or enqueue an alternative script if the version is lower.

[From here](http://wptheming.com/2010/12/check-wordpress-version/), a function to check the current version

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'is_version' ) ) {
    function is_version( $version = '3.3' ) {
        global $wp_version;
        if ( version_compare( $wp_version, $version, '>=' ) ) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And a relevant WPSE post: [Code to determine WP version check](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/9194)